# Iterating over a big MongoDB collection without running out of memory

Tags: php, mongodb, hhvm

I have a large Mongo collection I want to iterate over so I do something like that:

```
$cursor = $mongo->my_big_collection->find([]);

foreach ($cursor as $doc)
    do_something();
```

But I eventually run out of memory. I expected the cursor to free the memory after each document was processed. Why isn't that the case?
I tried calling `unset($doc)` at the end of my loop but that didn't help.

Right now I have to do something like this to get around the issue (processing the documents by batch and calling `unset()` on the cursor after each batch):

```
for ($skip = 0; true; $skip += 1000)
{
    $cursor = $mongo->my_big_collection->find()->skip($skip)->limit(1000);

    if (!$cursor->hasNext())
        break;

    foreach ($cursor as $doc)
        do_something();

    unset($cursor);
}
```

This seems awkward. The whole point of iterators is to not have to do this. Is there a better way?

I'm using hhvm 3.12 with [mongofill](https://github.com/mongofill/mongofill).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MongoCursor.php**

```
/**
 * Advances the cursor to the next result
 *
 * @return void - NULL.
 */
public function next()
{
    $this->doQuery();
    $this->fetchMoreDocumentsIfNeeded(); // <<< add documents to $this->documents

    $this->currKey++;
}

/**
 * Return the next object to which this cursor points, and advance the
 * cursor
 *
 * @return array - Returns the next object.
 */
public function getNext()
{
    $this->next();

    return $this->current();
}
```

When you iterate through the cursor, it will store in the cursors all the documents `$this->documents`. 
Nothing clear this collection of document. 
You could try to implement an iteration that remove the documents of `$this->documents` after getting them maybe ?

Comment: This also looks like an issue you should report to mongofill directly on GitHub as well :)